# Why is the second coefficient the sum of the solutions?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have an equation in the form:
$$x^n+a_{n-1} \cdot x^{n-1}+...+a_1 \cdot x+a_0=0$$
it is known that $a_{n-1}$is the sum the n solutions. But I can't understand why.
Can someone help me to understand?(I've met this in the study of third grade equations)

Comment: Also, there is a sign there.  If $n$ is odd, then $a_{n-1}$ is the negative of the sum of the solutions.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the second coefficient is the opposite of the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is a small part of what's called Vieta's formulas.

If you let $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ be the solutions of your equation, then, if we call $p(x)$ the left hand side of your equation, you know that $$p(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2) \cdots(x-x_n) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x+a_0. $$

Now just expand the parentheses and you derive what you are asking.